# Button background change on click

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to create custom controls for my HTML5 audio player.

At current, i have my Play/Pause button, however, on the button being clicked, i'd like to change the current Play background to a Pause symbol.

The JS works perfectly, just can't figure out how to switch backgrounds.

HTML5:

```
<div id="myButtons">
<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()"></button>
<input id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" type="range" onchange="setVolume()" />
<button id="mute" onclick="toggleMute()">Mute</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function togglePlayPause() {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
      playpause.title = "";
      playpause.innerHTML = "";
      audio.play();
   }
   else {
      playpause.title = "";
      playpause.innerHTML = "";
      audio.pause();
   }
```

Comment: Also, depending on what you want to do there are some neat things that can be done with ONLY css. http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function togglePlayPause() {

       var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");

       if (audio.paused || audio.ended) {
          playpause.style.backgroundImage="url(play.png)";
          playpause.title = "";
          playpause.innerHTML = "";
          audio.play();
       }
       else {
          playpause.style.backgroundImage="url(pause.png)";
          playpause.title = "";
          playpause.innerHTML = "";
          audio.pause();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be better if you'd just add some classes :

```
.button-icon-play {
  background: url(...) /*other background styling stuff*/;
}

.button-icon-pause {
  background: url(...) /*other background styling stuff*/;
}
```

Add the `button-icon-play` by default to your element ,and then in your JS, just do :

```
/*Switch to pause button*/
playpause.className = 'button-icon-pause';

/*Switch to play button*/
playpause.className = 'button-icon-play';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the css value using jquery

```
var playpause = $("#playpause");
var foo = false;

    playpause.click(function(){
        if(foo===false){
        playpause.css("background", pause-background-url);
         foo=true;
        }
        else{
          foo=false;
         playpause.css("background", play-background-url);
        }
    }};
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear in explaining. 
I currently have a background set, of a play icon.
On the button being pressed, i'd like it to change to the pause icon

Comment: @Tadeck While I would have mentioned something like... "If you are ok with jQuery" I for one like to see a jQuery version on javascript question...since a vast majority of pages DO use it.  Since this is a knowledge sharing site I would say it's good to have here even if not DIRECTLY beneficial to the OP. (Just my $.02)

Comment: i rarely use bare js. to be honest navnath's solution didnt even come to my mind. his makes more sense though.

Comment: @Jared: Any digits? I agree many people use it, but adding whole framework to support background changing only is an overkill - especially taking into account that OP did not write `$('#playpause').html('')`, but used vanilla JavaScript. Your arguments reminds me of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45176/176673)). This answer assumed too much, did not even saying a word about jQuery requirement ([proof](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16127778/1)). Even if majority of sites use jQuery, it does not mean it has to be used on other sites.

Comment: @Tadeck yes this answer is overkill. again navnath's answer is better. and again i rarely use pure js. and i guess i jumped to the answer really quickly so my first anwser looks like that.

Comment: @Tadeck Again, I suggested it has value simply because a LARGE number of websites DO use JavaScript even if the OP didn't.  Like you said this doesn't mean that the OP's sites needs to add jQuery to it, but it's not out of line to think that someone might come across this question and already have jQuery integrated into the site.  My point is simply that while this answer has little value to the OP based only on the question.  This doesn't mean that there isn't value to it to someone else...